# Rewrite until in Haskell

Tags: haskell

im trying to rewrite until in Haskell

Here's how i tried:

```
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
until m w x
  | m x == True = x
  | otherwise = take 1 (dropWhile (not m) (iterate w x))
```

The problem is the (not m) part

Comment: BTW `take` returns a list (here a list with (at most) 1 element). You are probably looking for `head`, which just gets the first element (and crashes if there isn't one).

Comment: Also, `m x == True` is equivalent to just `m x`

Comment: (This is unrelated to your problem.) What bug do you believe will arise if you omit the first guard (`| m x == True = x`) entirely? Does the compiler agree with you?

Comment: What is this function supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can write `(not . m)`, which is called "function composition" - the same as `\x -> not (m x)`.